# Do I need to flash stock recovery same as my stock rom's version?

Tags: recovery-mode

I am using Android 4.1.2 with TWRP custom recovery, now I want to flash stock recovery, do I need to flash the recovery from 4.1.2 stock ROM or any version of stock recovery is ok ? Thanks